# Losing DateTimeOffset precision when using C#

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

I have a SQL Server table with a CreatedDate field of type DateTimeOffset(2).
A sample value which is in the table is 2010-03-01 15:18:58.57 -05:00

As an example, from within C# I retrieve this value like so:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CreatedDate FROM Entities WHERE EntityID = 2", cn);  
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
DataTable dt =new DataTable();  
da.Fill(dt);
```

And I look at the value:
MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());

The result is 2010-03-01 15:18:58 -05:00, which is missing the .57 that is stored in the database.

If I look at dt.Rows[0][0] in the Watch window, I also do not see the .57, so it appears it has been truncated.

Can someone shed some light on this?  I need to use the date to match up with other records in the database and the .57 is needed.

Thanks!
Darvis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have millisecond precision.

Here's an article that goes into the details:

[Advanced SQL Server DATE and DATETIME Handling](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/advanced_date_datetime_handling_p1.aspx)

**EDIT**

I'm guessing C# shouldn't show the same behavior. Keep in mind that the `DateTime.ToString()` method doesn't include milliseconds unless you specify a Format Provider.

The Watch window would also be showing you `ToString()`. Try setting a Breakpoint and use the Inspector to get the more detailed information being stored and see if you mililseconds are there.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  The link is helpful.  What is Inspector?

Comment: It's simply the ability to mouse over a variable after hitting a breakpoint and seeing its value.

Comment: "SQL Server doesn't have millisecond precision." Really? The OP specifically stated that (s)he's using the datetimeoffset column type, which can have a precision down to 100 nanoseconds http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx

Comment: Justin, broken link, do you know where the reference has been relocated?

Comment: @r2evans I'm guessing http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/advanced-date-datetime-handling/ should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Fill should change the data in the dataset to match the data in the datasource -- have you tried any other methods to retrieve the data to see if other classes retrieve the data in the format you are hoping for?  Simple tests like sqldatasource/gridview, etc